# Clang won't compile a template specialization that gcc will

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, template-specialization

Gcc compiles this fine, but Clang (trunk) refuses with the message:

```
<source>:7:8: error: class template partial specialization is not more specialized than the primary template [-Winvalid-partial-specialization]
```

https://godbolt.org/g/h8rsWC

```
template<class T, T x>
struct S{};

template<int& x>
struct S<int&, x> { };
```

Is this code correct or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This only manifests in `-std=c++17` and later. The "more specialized" determination requires [synthesizing a pair of function templates from the class templates](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.order), [synthesizing unique types, values, and templates for the template parameters](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order), and finally [performing template argument deduction in both directions](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial). A template is "more specialized" if deduction succeeds in one direction but not the other.

Here, Clang is deducing `T` from two sources and getting divergent results:

- from the explicitly specified `int&`, it deduces `T := int&`.
- from the non-type argument `x`, it deduces `T := int` per the usual deduction rules (which generally do not deduce a reference type). This ability to deduce from the type of a non-type template argument was added in C++17.

This makes the deduction fail in both directions, so the partial specialization fails the "more specialized" test.

This looks like a defect in the standard. The workaround is to wrap the `T` in the original template in a non-deduced context.

Comment: sure makes sense, but I'm not getting what you mean as a solution. could you add an example wrapping?